# Error with the input_shape expected to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (73257, 32, 32)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, shapes

I have greyscale images of this shape: `x_train_grey.shape = (73257, 32, 32)`

I specify the first layer like this:

`Flatten(input_shape=(32,32,1)'`
Because I don't pass the batch_size and the greyscale images have only 1 channel. But I get this error:

`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got an array with shape (73257, 32, 32)`

I don't understand what is wrong, please help. I understand this has been asked many times, but I cannot find a solution.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm still learning this stuff too but I would guess that "1" as a dimension's number of entries isn't possible. Even if it is possible, it's a start. "1" as a size of an axis doesn't make sense to me.
Anyone else?

Comment: Thanks, indeed `input_shape=(32,32)` seems to be working fine

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably lies in the way you are passing your data to your model. If your input shape is `(batch_size, 32, 32)` then try something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

grey_scale_images = tf.random.normal((64, 32, 32))

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32,32,1)))

print(model(grey_scale_images).shape)
# (64, 1024)
```

Update: Both `input_shape=(32,32,1)` and `input_shape=(32,32)` will work. It depends how you are feeding your data to your model:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

grey_scale_images = tf.random.normal((64, 32, 32))
Y = tf.random.normal((64, 1024))
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32, 32, 1)))
model.compile(loss='MSE')
model.fit(grey_scale_images, Y)
```

Comment: Actually, simply passing `input_shape=(32,32)` has worked, thanks!

Comment: I think you are mistaken...Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks but I am not quite sure this is right. I tried `input_shape=(32,32,1)` but it's not working. What do you suggest needs to be done before passing that instead of `input_shape=(32,32)`? Is there some rule that says `(32,32,1)` should be used over `(32,32)` or does it not matter, as you say both options work?

Comment: Check the bottom of my answer. As I said both work but it depends on what your data looks like